# Significance of API request signing over HTTPS

Tags: rest, https

Is there some good use case of API request signing over HTTPS.

Request signing is used to verify the identity of the user and protect data in transit. This can be done by authorization header for the first part and SSL takes care of the second part. Do I still need API request signing if I am using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Usually (as long as you don't use HTTPS with client certificates) HTTPS protects the communication and verifies the authenticity of the server.

API request signing on the other hand allows you to verify the authenticity of he client.

Therefore HTTPS and API request signing complement one another in a perfect way: Both communication partners can verify the authenticity of the other partner.

Comment: I can do that using authorization-header or custom header passing the username and password without request signing

Answer (score -1):

I think TLS won't help you with client authenticity unless you are using mutual TLS, and you somehow tie the TLS session with the application session.